# Converting DOB format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called NAMES that has a DOB column in `nvarchar` which for some reason will not convert to date, which is fine as long as I can run a snippet of code to convert it which is actually preferable. So here is the dilemma... some dates are `m/d/yyyy` and some are `mm/dd/yyyy` .

Examples:

```
2/4/1986
10/8/1999
4/24/1988
12/13/1975
```

I'd like to run a snippet of code to convert everything to a standard `mm/dd/yyyy` format. Thank you in advance...

Comment: How can you tell which one is `d/m/y` and which one is `m/d/y`? Is that first date Feb 4 or April 2, 1986?

Comment: Yes its always month, day then year but a month like January instead of being represented as 01 is just 1. the 3rd day is 3 instead of 03, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question you mention that you can't convert to proper dates (which I guess is due to invalid data) and that you're happy to keep it as a character value.

While I think the proper action would be to fix the invalid values and convert the column to a proper date(time) type, maybe that's not possible.

If you really need to "fix" the character values then you could do an update using string functions like this:

```
update NAMES
set DOB = 
  case len(DOB)
    when 8 then '0' + stuff(DOB,3,0,'0')
  else 
    case charindex('/',DOB)
      when 2 then '0' + DOB
      else stuff(DOB,4,0,'0')
    end
  end
where len(DOB) < 10
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbc2d/1)

Be aware that it might not have top performance on large datasets.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you everyone who contributed.!!

Comment: now if the year of birth was /85 and needed to be /1985, what would be need to be added to the above script?

Comment: @Sal If the year can also be 2 characters long then logic suggests that the len(DOB) var be either 6, 7, 8, or 10. You would need to change the logic to reflect that and handle the different cases, and in the case where the year part (which you can test using a combo of charindex and len) is 2 chars you can use stuff to inject 19 at the right position (or 20 perhaps depending on year value). it's not terribly complicated but requires some careful thought about the edge cases etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select convert(nvarchar,convert(date,dt,101),101) as dt
from   tbl;
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8faf1/7/0

If you want to convert to actual date values, more simply run:

```
select convert(date,dt,101) as dt
from   tbl;
```